# Do potted flowers count towards beehives or just planted ones?

Tags: hearthlands

The beehive's description states it is most efficient with at least 8 flowers within the hive's range. Does this count potted flowers? I'm guessing it only means flowers planted from a forester but I cannot find details on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. Turns out you can right-click the beehives and it'll tell you how many flowers are in range.

[image: Beehive]